# How can I turn these instructions into a loop?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

So I have a **subject folder** which contains subjects such as :

- Geography
- Math

These subjects are files.
And each one of them contain the name of a student with his mark.

---

Sor for example it will be,

**For Geography**

- Mattew 15
- Elena 14

**And Math** :

- Matthew 10
- Elena 19

I also have a **student folder** which is empty for now.
And the purpose of this folder is to put inside of it :

1. The name of the student as the name of the file;
2. The marks of all subjets this student received.

---

**So here is my code** :

```
#### Subjects folder #####
GEOGRAPHY="/home/subject/geography"
MATH="/home/subject/math"

##### Registration student #####
studentMatthew="/home/student/Matthew"
Geo_Matthew=$(grep "Matthew" "$GEOGRAPHY" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentMatthew"
Math_Matthew=$(grep "Matthew" "$MATH" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentMatthew"

studentElena="/home/student/Elena"
Geo_Elena=$(grep "Elena" "$GEOGRAPHY" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentElena"
Math_Elena=$(grep "Elena" "$MATH" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentElena"


##### SHOW RESULT #####
echo "Geography" >> "$studentMatthew" "$Geo_Matthew"
echo "Math" >> "$studentMatthew" "$Geo_Matthew"

echo "Geography" >> "$studentElena" "$Geo_Elena"
echo "Math" >> "$studentElena" "$Math_Elena"
```

This works perfectly.
But it is not a very good practice to write it this way.

Because if for example I add another student let's say Patrick, I'll have to **manually** add his marks for both Geography and Math.

---

So it'll be :

```
##### Registration Patrick #####
studentPatrick="/home/student/Patrick"
Geo_Patrick=$(grep "Patrick" "$GEOGRAPHY" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentPatrick"
Math_Patrick=$(grep "Patrick" "$MATH" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentPatrick"

##### SHOW RESULT PATRICK #####
echo "Geography" >> "$studentPatrick" "$Geo_Patrick"
echo "Math" >> "$studentPatrick" "$Math_Patrick"
```

And it'll be redundant..

---

So I was wondering,

Is there a way to refactor this code into a loop? So if I add a new student, I won't have to manually  write it again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for subjfile in /home/subject/*; do
    awk -v subj="$(basename "$subjfile")" '{ print subj, $2 >>"/home/student/" $1 }' "$subjfile"
done
```

This would iterate over all the subject files.  The `$subjfile` value would be something like `/home/subject/Math` or `/home/subject/Geography` etc., depending on what subjects were available.

The `awk` program would open each of these files in turn and print the subject name (which is the "basename" of the pathname in `$subjfile`, i.e. `Math` or `Geography`) followed by the mark in that subject (column 2 of the `$subjfile` file).

This would be written to `"/home/student/" $1` which is a pathname under `/home/student`.  The `$1` is the *first* column of the `$subjfile` file, which is the name of the student.

The code assumes that the `student` directory is empty when the script starts running (or it will append to the files in there).

Running on the given data (including the misspelling of one of the names), this would create three files in `/home/student`:

```
$ cat Elena
Geography 14
Math 19
```

```
$ cat Mattew
Geography 15
```

```
$ cat Matthew
Math 10
```

Note that the student names are picked from the files under `/home/subject` and never hard-coded in the script.  Also, the various subjects depends on what files are available in the `/home/subject` directory.

---

Would you want to do this without involving `awk`:

```
for subjfile in /home/subject/*; do
    subject=$( basename "$subjfile" )
    while read -r name marks; do
        printf '%s %d\n' "$subject" "$marks" >>"/home/student/$name"
    done <"$subjfile"
done
```

Comment: The next step is to understand _why_ it works... and what the failure conditions are, and why.

Comment: I understood the while loop, I'm looking forward now to understand your first method.

I'll manage thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you do something like this:

```
# loop over all files in the student directory
for studentfile in /home/student/*; do
    # take just the name of the student (the file name without the path)
    studentname="${studentfile##*/}"

    # uncomment the next line to clear the student files before populating them
    # > "$studentfile" 

    # loop over all subject files
    for subject in /home/subject/*; do
        # again, remove the path
        subject="${subject##*/}"
        grep "$studentname" "$subject" | cut -d' ' -f2 >> "$studentfile"
    done
done
```

This assuming that the file names for the students and subjects are exactly the same as the labels used for them within the files and that there exists a file already for each student.

The `${var##*/}` expansion takes the value of `$var` with the longest prefix matching `*/` removed, i.e. it leaves just the path. We need both for the student, since we use just `Matthew` for the `grep` but `/home/student/Matthew` for the output redirection.

Note that your assignment `Geo_Matthew=$(grep "Matthew" "$GEOGRAPHY" | cut -d' ' -f2) > "$studentMatthew"` has an extra redirection in it, the assignment doesn't create any output, so the redirection only truncates the file named in `$studentMatthew`. You can just redirect the output of `grep` to the file and remove the command substitution, the `Geo_Matthew` variable, and the later `echo`.

This would be better done with an awk or Perl script instead of a shell script, but the above is a possible way to arrange the commands you have in loops.

Comment: Thank you for this version too !
I'll take a note of this.